# How can I exactly match a string inside of a larger string?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

I have the following enum declared:

```
public enum EtcMethod
{
    ACCORD,
    COROLLA,
    COROLLA_S,
    CAMRY,
    CIVIC
}
```

On my form, I have a handful of controls with their Tag property set:

```
myControl1.Tag = "ACCORD";
myControl2.Tag = "COROLLA";
myControl3.Tag = "CIVIC COROLLA_S CAMRY";
```

Then I'm checking the controls' tags in a loop to see if any of the values are found:

```
    private void HideControls(EtcMethod etcMethod, LayoutControlGroup lcg)
    {
        foreach (BaseLayoutItem ctl in lcg.Items)
        {
            if (ctl.GetType() == typeof (LayoutControlItem))
            {
                LayoutControlItem item = (LayoutControlItem)ctl;

                if (item.Tag.ToString().IndexOf(etcMethod.ToString()) >= 0)
                    item.Visibility = LayoutVisibility.Always;
                else
                    item.Visibility = LayoutVisibility.Never;
            }
        }
    }
```

But the problem with this is, for example, if `etcMethod` is `COROLLA` and `item.Tag.ToString()` is `"COROLLA_S"` that'll erroneously pass the check.

How can I make sure that it'll find an exact match instead of a "partial" match? In other words, I would like it to behave as if you checked off the "Match whole word" option using Visual Studio's Find feature.

The only solution I could think of would be to check the value of the character at `etcMethod.Lenght+1` and see if it's a space (indicating the beginning of another enum value) or if that position even exists (indicating the end of the tag), but that seems particularly sloppy.

Comment: find the start index of your match in the larger string and then: `largerString.Substring(indexOfMatch, lengthOfMatch)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you `Split` it and use Contains ?

```
if (item.Tag.ToString().Split().Contains(etcMethod.ToString()))
```

This will first split your `Tag` on space, if it hasn't space it just turn it into a string array, then using `Contains` on array will look for exact match.

Comment: Ahh, I always forget about Split- use it so infrequently. Thanks, thi seems to be the most eloquent solution, however I can't call Contains as it says `Cannot access explicit implementation of IList.Contains`. What I did do was break it up into two segments and iterate over the value that Split() returned.

Comment: @sab669 add `using System.Linq` directive to your project

Comment: Perfect! Not sure why VS didn't recommend that... It's usually pretty good about recommending that sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

This may be one solution:

```
if (item.Tag.ToString() + " ").IndexOf(etcMethod.ToString() + " ") >= 0)
```

Comment: Looking at this, I suppose it would work but I prefer to stay away from unnecessary concatenation whenever possible.

Comment: @GrantWinney That's why he appends an empty space to `item.Tag` before calling `IndexOf`, so both values will always end in an empty space.